# Python — why is perimeter undefined?

Tags: python, syntax

Why is Python reporting that the variable `perimeter` is undefined?

```
#The first function will accept the length and width of a rectangle as its two parameters and return the rectangles perimeter
length=float(input("What is the length of your rectangle?"))
width=float(input("What is the width of your rectangle?"))
def rectanglePerimeter(length,width): #the parameter limits , it will accept the length and the width 
    perimeter= (2*length) + (2*width ) #here we implement the equation for the rectangles perimeter 
    return perimeter #return the result 
def rectangleArea(length,width):
    area= length*width 
    return area 
if perimeter> area:
    print ("the perimeter is larger than the area")
elif perimeter<area:
    print ("the area is larger than the perimeter")
    if perimeter == area:
        print ("the area and the perimeter are equal")
```

Comment: Please highlight your code and click the curly braces, to format.

Comment: That's not how programming works.

Comment: I already did the formatting this time.  I meant for next time.

Comment: @user2548833: why do you think `perimeter` *should* be defined? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't called your functions; you have only defined them. To call them, you have to do something like `rectanglePerimeter(length, width)` or `rectangleArea(length, width)`.

```
perimeter = rectanglePerimeter(length, width) # Where length and width are our inputs
area = rectangleArea(length, width) # Where once again length and width are our inputs
```

Also, your if/elif statements seem to be a bit off:

```
if perimeter > area:
    print ("the perimeter is larger than the area")
elif perimeter < area:
    print ("the area is larger than the perimeter")
elif perimeter == area: # This should not be nested, and it should be another elif. Infact, you could probably put an else: here.
    print ("the area and the perimeter are equal")
```

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

1. You should store the results of the function calls into a variable.
2. You can replace the last if statement with an else (since the third case only ever happens when they are equal)

```
#The first function will accept the length and width of a rectangle as its two parameters and return the rectangles perimeter
length=float(input("What is the length of your rectangle?"))
width=float(input("What is the width of your rectangle?"))

def rectanglePerimeter(length,width): #the parameter limits , it will accept the length and the width 
    perimeter= (2*length) + (2*width ) #here we implement the equation for the rectangles perimeter 
    return perimeter #return the result 

def rectangleArea(length,width):
    area= length*width 
    return area 

# need to call the functions, and store the results into variables here:
perimeter = rectanglePerimeter(length, width)
area = rectangleArea(length, width)

if perimeter> area:
    print ("the perimeter is larger than the area")
elif perimeter<area:
    print ("the area is larger than the perimeter")
else: # At this point, perimeter == area
    print ("the area and the perimeter are equal")
```

Comment: i need it to also return the perimeter and are along with the comparisons at the end. that is my goal.

Comment: Yeah, see the comment within the code that says "need to call..."

Answer (score 0):

`perimeter` is a local variable, but you're using it outside the function.  In fact, you're never actually calling any of your functions.

Comment: so would i have to change the name of the variable?

Comment: @user2548833, no, the name is not the issue.  As I said, you're not even calling your functions.  I suggest you consult a good Python introductory tutorial or book.